# Optimistic locking in web applications

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, optimistic-locking

We are building a customer provisioning tool for our multi-tenant application. Multiple users can work on the same configuration and hence we want to avoid conflicts. We know that optimistic locking is the way to go. But wondering how to show the **delta** to the user who has performed the conflicting action? Showing back a status message is easy but we would also like to show which data is in the conflict state. Appreciate your ideas.

EDIT: 
The data is not persisted as set of tables in the database but it is serailized to an XML file and that is what is saved in the db.

Comment: You could use a framework like hibernate envers to keep track of all changes and who made them. The delta would be a matter of comparing the versions. Alternatively you could just put the object you provide your user in his session. When a concurency exception occurs, compare what's in the database to that object and there is your delta.

Answer (score 0):

you can use libarries like http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibdiff/

Comment: I think it is just to compare the files but not the object graphs. Is that correct? There is very little documentation on this.